Different Aura component List behaviour in scratch org vs production
I have this strange issue using lists in Aura. I have checked basic things like Lightning Web Security (enabled) and Lightning Debug Mode (enabled) but can't work out why this is happening.
The code:
<aura:attribute name="myListOfRecords" type="Custom_Object__c[]" access="private" default="[]"/>
Doing the following in the helper:
component.get("v.myListOfRecords")
In scratch org this is an empty list.
In production org this is string "[]".
(We are packaging our code using first-generation managed packages)
Anyone know what the cause could be?

If typeof produces "string" based on the returned value, this is (and you probably know this) a bug. Can you reproduce this bug on your prod org with an Aura component that contains nothing but the attribute declaration and an init handler? Lacking user permissions shouldn't lead to a string here, but just to make sure: You are admin user on prod and/or have access to the respective object? (Can you reproduce this problem with other objects on prod?)
